# Struggling to reference a variable in copy command .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a small script to copy a few files over for my work. Every month the destination folders will change so using variables would make my life much easier. As soon as I reference a variable in the destination pat of the copy command it tells me destination is not found. Not a pro but any advice will help. Thanks.

Below is my code:

```
1* SET MONTH=8. August 2021
2* SET YEAR=2021 
3* SET ACGROV="4. Grove Cashup August 2021.xlsx"
4* SET ACMENL="7. Menlyn Cashup August 2021.xlsx"
5* SET ACILAN="6. ILANGA CASHUP August 2021.xlsx"
6* SET MENL="8. Menlyn Cashup August 2021.xlsx"
7* SET GROV="8. Grove Cashup August 2021.xlsx"
8* SET ILAN="8. Cash-up Ilanga - August 2021.xlsx"
9* SET COPYTO=C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/ACCOUNTS/Cash Ups/%YEAR%/%MONTH%
10* cd C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/ACCOUNTS/Cash Ups/%YEAR%/%MONTH%/
11* Del %ACGROV%
12* Del %ACMENL%
13* Del %ACILAN%
14* cd C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/The Fun Company Cash Up Summaries/Cash Up/Ilanga/%YEAR%/
15* copy %ILAN% "%COPYTO%"
16* cd C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/The Fun Company Cash Up Summaries/Cash Up/Grove/%YEAR%/
17* copy %GROV% "%COPYTO%"
18* cd C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/The Fun Company Cash Up Summaries/Cash Up/menlyn/%YEAR%/
19* copy %MENL% "%COPYTO%"
20* cd C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/ACCOUNTS/Cash Ups/%YEAR%/%MONTH%/
21* ren %ILAN% %ACILAN%
22* ren %MENL% %ACMENL%
23* ren %GROV% %ACGROV%
24* timeout /t -1
```

Comment: Bash and windows batch files are something completely different. I fixed the tag for you. Also, for the future, format you code as such, see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Watch your spaces. You have a stray trailing space with `2* SET YEAR=2021 `. Use recommended syntax `set "var=value"` to avoid that (note the position of the quotes - they don't become part of the variable name or value)

Comment: 1. Quote *all* paths, also those stored in variables, like `del "%VAR%"` or `copy "D:\dir\file.ext" "%DEST%"`, for instance. 2. Follow Stephan's recommendation of using the quoted `set` syntax, so the quotes do not become part of the assigned value; this is particularly useful when concatenating strings, like `"D:\dir\%NAME%"`; furthermore, whitespaces and other special characters become protected. 3. `cd C:\…` should be replaced by `cd /D "C:\…"` to change the drive as well. 4. The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`; whilst many commands accept both, some may return unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan is correct you should use that syntax because for example:

```
SET ACGROV="4. Grove Cashup August 2021.xlsx"
```

if you do:

```
echo %ACGROV%
```

You will get the content of the variable which will be:

"4. Grove Cashup August 2021.xlsx"

So do that and also take out the numbers 1*...24* and everything else looks pretty much correct although I recommend u using cd with "" when there are folders with spaces in the names:

```
cd "C:/Users/dranr/Dropbox/The Fun Company Cash Up Summaries/Cash Up/menlyn/%YEAR%/"
```